# Error in implementing stack in c

Tags: c

I am trying to implement `stack` in c. Here is what I have done-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stack 
{
    char * data;
    struct stack * next;
}stack;
stack * top1;

void push(char* data,stack * top)
{
    stack* temp;
    temp = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    if (!temp)
        return;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = top;
    top = temp;
}

int isEmpty(stack * top)
{
    if(top == NULL)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

char* pop(stack * top)
{
    stack* temp; char*data;
    if (isEmpty(top) == 1)
        return "FALSE";
    temp = top;
    data = top->data;
    top = top->next;
    free(temp);
    return data;
}

void display(stack * top)
{   stack* temp = top;
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        printf("%s \n",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

 int main()
 {
    top1=(stack *)malloc (sizeof(stack));
    push("aa",top1);
    push("bb",top1);
    push("cc",top1);
    display(top1);
    char* data;
    data =pop(top1);
    printf("Pop = %s\n",data );
    data =pop(top1);
    printf("Pop = %s\n",data );
    display(top1);
 }
```

But I am getting the following error-

```
(null) 
Pop = (null)
*** Error in `./exe': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000025cc010 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The code appears to be correct, yet it is giving the error.

Comment: There is some undefined behavior in here; you allocate `top1` using `malloc()` but you never initialize it --- yet you rely on its contents. The real problem though is, for example, `top = temp;` at the bottom of your `push()` function is useless... it only modifies a local variable before the function returns. The same bad pattern is in `pop()`. _The code appears to be correct_ - based on what? Certainly not the results ;)

Comment: Please don't cast the return value of malloc(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: 'The code appears to be correct, yet it is giving the error' - please explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `push` and `pop`, you pass in the *value* of `top1`.  So when you manipulate the local variable `top` in both cases, it has no effect on `top1`.

You need to pass the the *address* of `top1` to these functions in order to modify its contents.  Also, you should initialize `top1` to NULL.

```
void push(char* data,stack ** top)
{
    stack* temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(stack));   // don't cast the return value of malloc
    if (!temp)
        return;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = *top;
    *top = temp;
}
...
char* pop(stack ** top)
{
    stack* temp; char*data;
    if (isEmpty(*top) == 1)
        return "FALSE";
    temp = *top;
    data = (*top)->data;
    *top = (*top)->next;
    free(temp);
    return data;
}
...
 int main()
 {
    top1=NULL;
    push("aa",&top1);
    push("bb",&top1);
    push("cc",&top1);
    display(top1);
    char* data;
    data =pop(&top1);
    printf("Pop = %s\n",data );
    data =pop(&top1);
    printf("Pop = %s\n",data );
    display(top1);
 }
```